# free struct too many arguments in function call

Tags: c++, function, struct, arguments, free

i have a list struct:

```
typedef struct FaceNode{
    FaceNode *next;
    Face *aFace;
    FaceNode *prev; 
} FaceNode;
```

I use this struct as a member:

```
FaceNode *myFaces;
```

and initialize it like this (in a constructor)

```
this->myFaces = (FaceNode*)malloc(sizeof(FaceNode)*1);
```

Later I want to free it as follows:

```
FaceNode *theCurrentFaceNode;
Face* theCurrentFace;

while(this->myFaces->next){

   theCurrentFaceNode = this->myFaces;
   theCurrentFace = theCurrentFaceNode->aFace;

   this->myFaces = this->myFaces->next;

   free(theCurrentFace);
   free(theCurrentFaceNode);
}
```

Now my IDE tells me: "Error, too many arguments in function call" for the free call.

What is wrong about that?

Cheers

Comment: What's wrong is that this is "C with classes", not C++. If you didn't use `this->`, this would be just C code.

Comment: Is it a namespace issue? I mean, is there another "free()" defined in your app that takes no arguments?

Comment: As @Xeo implies, you should probably be using `std::list<Face>` here. That will also make it much easier to switch to a more sensible data structure than a linke list after you come to your senses.

Comment: He's probably doing this as an exercise, not to actually write production code.

Comment: @Seth: No excuse to use `malloc`, `free` and `typedef struct Name {...} Name;`. That's all stupid C cruft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have evidently declared a function of your own named `free`, and the compiler is finding that instead of the one you thought you were calling. Use the scope-resolution operator to call the global function:

```
::free(theCurrentFace);
```

Or find the other `free` function and give it a different name. It might be a member of the class you're implementing; look in the class's ancestor classes, too.

Comment: yes i am an idiot :D (cant accept your answer under 10 minutes, I check it later!)